# c++ linux How to measure the number of disk accesses?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm reading "*Introduction to Algorithms*" Chapter 18, "B-Trees".

> Often, accessing a page of information and reading it from a disk takes longer
> than examining all the information read. For this reason, in this chapter we shall
> look separately at the two principal components of the running time:
>
> - the number of disk accesses, and
> - the CPU (computing) time.
>   We measure the number of disk accesses in terms of the number of pages of information that need to be read from or written to the disk. ......

> We model disk operations in our pseudocode as follows. Let `x` be a pointer to an
> object. If the object is currently in the computer's main memory, then we can refer
> to the attributes of the object as usual: `x.key`, for example. If the object referred to by `x` resides on disk, however, then we must perform the operation `DISK-READ(x)` to read object `x` into main memory before we can refer to its attributes. (We assume that if `x` is already in main memory, then `DISK-READ(x)` requires no disk accesses; it is a "no-op.") Similarly, the operation `DISK-WRITE(x)` is used to save any changes that have been made to the attributes of object `x`.

For studying purpose I want to implement and fully simulate this using C++ and several Linux APIs.

Two years ago, I had already written an in-memory B-Tree([link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248231/c-b-tree-in-c20-iterator-support)), but this time I want to tweak this and combine it with the followings:

1. A memory map of a file (something like `boost::mapped_file`)
2. A custom allocator that uses the memory resource from 1.

so that I can track measure the disk read/writes. I'm considering using Linux system APIs but I'm not familiar with them, are there any useful references and resources to get started?

Comment: theoretical according to the model, or real - because there's all sorts of stuff that gets in the way of the nice theoretical model, like [read-ahead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533811/weird-major-page-fault-number-when-reading-sequentially-randomly-in-mmap-regio).

Comment: For the number of actual major page faults (times the program tried to read a page and the page hadn't been loaded from disk) you can read from [`/proc/self/stat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and it's the 12th thing in the file